# D3.js color function each gauge section

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was searching for a gauge to display at a website and I discovered one. http://bl.ocks.org/msqr/3202712
I have one little problem with this one. I want to display different colors in each section because they are already set in other charts.

Currently it's using a gradient to color each section. Is  there a function to set separate colors to each section?

(a small piece of code)

```
var gauge = function(container, configuration) {
    var that = {};
    var config = {
        (...)
        arcColorFn  : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#e8e2ca'), d3.rgb('#3e6c0a'))
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your config object:

```
arcColorFn: d3.scale.quantize()
  .domain([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])
  .range(['orange','red','green','blue', 'purple'])
```

---

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
 <title>Gauge</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
 <style>
 body {
  font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 32px;
 }

 #power-gauge g.arc {
  fill: steelblue;
 }

 #power-gauge g.pointer {
  fill: #e85116;
  stroke: #b64011;
 }
 
 #power-gauge g.label text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: #666;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="power-gauge"></div>
 
<script>
var gauge = function(container, configuration) {
 var that = {};
 var config = {
  size      : 200,
  clipWidth     : 200,
  clipHeight     : 110,
  ringInset     : 20,
  ringWidth     : 20,
  
  pointerWidth    : 10,
  pointerTailLength   : 5,
  pointerHeadLengthPercent : 0.9,
  
  minValue     : 0,
  maxValue     : 10,
  
  minAngle     : -90,
  maxAngle     : 90,
  
  transitionMs    : 750,
  
  majorTicks     : 5,
  labelFormat     : d3.format(',g'),
  labelInset     : 10,
  
  arcColorFn     : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#e8e2ca'), d3.rgb('#3e6c0a'))
 };
 var range = undefined;
 var r = undefined;
 var pointerHeadLength = undefined;
 var value = 0;
 
 var svg = undefined;
 var arc = undefined;
 var scale = undefined;
 var ticks = undefined;
 var tickData = undefined;
 var pointer = undefined;

 var donut = d3.layout.pie();
 
 function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
 }
 
 function newAngle(d) {
  var ratio = scale(d);
  var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
  return newAngle;
 }
 
 function configure(configuration) {
  var prop = undefined;
  for ( prop in configuration ) {
   config[prop] = configuration[prop];
  }
  
  range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
  r = config.size / 2;
  pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);

  // a linear scale that maps domain values to a percent from 0..1
  scale = d3.scale.linear()
   .range([0,1])
   .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);
   
  ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
  tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {return 1/config.majorTicks;});
  
  arc = d3.svg.arc()
   .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
   .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
   .startAngle(function(d, i) {
    var ratio = d * i;
    return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
   })
   .endAngle(function(d, i) {
    var ratio = d * (i+1);
    return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
   });
 }
 that.configure = configure;
 
 function centerTranslation() {
  return 'translate('+r +','+ r +')';
 }
 
 function isRendered() {
  return (svg !== undefined);
 }
 that.isRendered = isRendered;
 
 function render(newValue) {
  svg = d3.select(container)
   .append('svg:svg')
    .attr('class', 'gauge')
    .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
    .attr('height', config.clipHeight);
  
  var centerTx = centerTranslation();
  
  var arcs = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'arc')
    .attr('transform', centerTx);
  
  arcs.selectAll('path')
    .data(tickData)
   .enter().append('path')
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
     return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
    })
    .attr('d', arc);
  
  var lg = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .attr('transform', centerTx);
  lg.selectAll('text')
    .data(ticks)
   .enter().append('text')
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
     var ratio = scale(d);
     var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
     return 'rotate(' +newAngle +') translate(0,' +(config.labelInset - r) +')';
    })
    .text(config.labelFormat);

  var lineData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0], 
      [0, -pointerHeadLength],
      [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
      [0, config.pointerTailLength],
      [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];
  var pointerLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone');
  var pg = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
    .attr('class', 'pointer')
    .attr('transform', centerTx);
    
  pointer = pg.append('path')
   .attr('d', pointerLine/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/ )
   .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle +')');
   
  update(newValue === undefined ? 0 : newValue);
 }
 that.render = render;
 
 function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {
  if ( newConfiguration  !== undefined) {
   configure(newConfiguration);
  }
  var ratio = scale(newValue);
  var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
  pointer.transition()
   .duration(config.transitionMs)
   .ease('elastic')
   .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +newAngle +')');
 }
 that.update = update;

 configure(configuration);
 
 return that;
};
</script>

<script>
function onDocumentReady() {
 var powerGauge = gauge('#power-gauge', {
  size: 300,
  clipWidth: 300,
  clipHeight: 300,
  ringWidth: 60,
  maxValue: 10,
  transitionMs: 4000,
  arcColorFn: d3.scale.quantize()
                .domain([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])
                .range(['orange','red','green','blue', 'purple'])
 });
 powerGauge.render();
 
 function updateReadings() {
  // just pump in random data here...
  powerGauge.update(Math.random() * 10);
 }
 
 // every few seconds update reading values
 updateReadings();
 setInterval(function() {
  updateReadings();
 }, 5 * 1000);
}

if ( !window.isLoaded ) {
 window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  onDocumentReady();
 }, false);
} else {
 onDocumentReady();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                    return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
                })
```

To get custom colors, you can change the above part of code snippet like given below.

```
var colors = ['rgb(246,107,122)', 'rgb(255,179,2)', 'rgb(10,203,188)'];
.attr('fill', function (d, i) {
            return colors[i]
          })
```